# Xbox one s controller button mapping is incorrect when connecting to android

Tags: technical-issues, controllers, xbox-one

The inputs for the controller do not output the correct buttons. For example. The x button and rb button don't work and my triggers control the analog stick. How can I change this? I connect via Bluetooth though that is not the problem.

Answer (score -1):

OK finally figured it out. Make sure you have windows 10 and have the anniversary update installed, if you don't a quick Google should help. Download the Xbox accessories app, plug in your controller, an update should appear. Download and your good to go. The update will not appear if the anniversary update isn't installed. You don't need to change the mapping at all, just plug in the controller and update the firmware of the controller itself, this also works on an xbox one.

Comment: Wait, so the mapping needs to be registered on a windows PC before it can be transferred to a phone?  This normally doesn't work for any other device.

Comment: I downloaded the Windows 10 Anniversary Update, as well as the Xbox One S controller update that appeared, but the buttons are still mapped incorrectly when using the controller with my Samsung Galaxy S6.